# Why does sorting a list return None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse, palindrome

My code is written in python 3 and it is meant to print out palindromes.
It should iterate through all the palindromic products of 2 3-digit numbers as shown below:

```
mylist=[]
for i in range(999,99,-1):
    for x in range(999, i-1, -1,):
        number=i*x
        number=str(number)
        if number==number[::-1]:
            #print(number)         
            mylist.append(number)
mylist=mylist.sort(reverse=True)
print(mylist)
```

Note the commented out print. When this was still in place, all the palindromes that should have been printed out came out.
When I run my code, without the `print` statement, the console only prints out 'None'.

As far as I can see my logic is in order, so why is this happening?
EDIT:
Also, when I sort my list in reverse order, 99999 comes first. I gather this is because python looks at the consecutive 9's and thinks it is the biggest.
However, is there an easy way to get the actual biggest number?

Comment: you bind `mylist` to the result of calling `.sort` which is an in-place operation that returns `None`. Just do `mylist.sort(reverse=True)`.

Comment: @Shawn Li Not sure what you mean in your edit, but numbers are sorted in increasing numeric order by default, but you added `reverse=True`, which will put the biggest number first - because well, it *is* the actual biggest number.

Comment: @JulienD they are not sorted by numeric order because 99999 comes first, but a number such as 101101 is bigger than 99999. So my point is can you make the numerically biggest number, the one closest to infinity, come first?

Comment: @Shawn Li I see. You are sorting strings (`number=str(number)`). Why not sort the numbers, them map them to string? Otherwise, you will have to specify the key function to `sort`: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions

Comment: @JulienD Thank you very much! Done!

Comment: "EDIT: Also," **Please don't do this**. The other question is also a duplicate (which I have linked as well); but questions on Stack Overflow are supposed to be **one** question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`list.sort()` always returns None (the list is sorted in-place). What you want is `sorted(list)` which returns a new sorted list.

Then you can sort them like this:

```
mylist = [int(x) for x in mylist]
mylist.sort(reverse=True)
mylist = [str(x) for x in mylist]
```