# Python: Sort a list and print it out with a for loop - 'NoneType' object is not iterable'

Tags: python, list, sorting, for-loop

I have created a random list with numbers:

```
numbers = [8, 2, 17, 99, 12]
```

And I want to print them out with a for loop and permanently sort the numbers in increasing order.

I was able to do that, but i'm not sure if I am using the short way to do that.

```
numbers.sort()
for number in numbers:
   print (number)
```

I solved that with the code above, but my first instict was to do this:

```
for number in numbers.sort():
   print (number)
```

But the following error was found: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

Is there a way to sort the numbers in the "for placeholder_variable in variable" or the only way is with the first code? I have to sort them first and then make the for loop?

Thank you.

Comment: `numbers.sort()` sorts the list in place.  It changes the list, and returns nothing.  Calling `sorted(numbers)` returns the sorted list, but leaves the original list alone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047581/python-sort-on-a-list-of-a-set-returns-none, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169571/why-does-sorting-a-list-return-none, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710129/sort-returns-none, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is:

```
for number in sorted(numbers):
   print (number)
```

`numbers.sort()` sorts your list in place but does not return anything itself.